# Comodule structure on finite dimensional Hopf algebra

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

Actually I am trying to establish that the following are equivalent for $f\in H^*$:
(i) $f\in \pi(H^*)$. where $\pi(H^*)$ is the vector subspace of $H^*$ (the subspace of coinvariants).

(ii) $f:H \rightarrow k$ is an $H$ comodule map via $\delta_k:l\mapsto 1_H\otimes l$ for $l\in k$.

(iii) $fg=\epsilon_{H^*} (g)f$ for all $g\in H^*$.

I can pass from (i) to (ii) but passing from (ii) to (iii) and (iii) to (i) is little bit scary for me. Please I need a clue. Thanks everyone.!!

**Edit:** The thing here is that I try using the comodule structure established on $f$, but I cannot figure out where I wil be heading to because the connection in relation to $g\in H^*$ in proving the properties (iii) is hidden to me.   Thanks.